# Scheduling Audio in SpriteKit - Swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, scheduled-tasks, skaction

I'm trying to play random sounds in a game menu, it's actually birds cheeping.
So there are many bird sounds, but I wish them to be randomised.

I've previously done this using `schedule` along the lines of:

```
 this->schedule(schedule_selector(HelloWorld::birdsound),3.2);
```

Where:

```
void HelloWorld::birdsound(){
    int soundnum=arc4random()%9+1;

    switch (soundnum) {
        case 1:
            appdelegate->bird1();
            break;
        case 2:
            appdelegate->bird2();
            break;
          .
          .
          .
        case 9:
            appdelegate->bird9();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Thus, playing the random sound e.g., `bird1()`:

```
void AppDelegate::bird1(){
    CocosDenshion::SimpleAudioEngine::sharedEngine()->stopAllEffects();
    CocosDenshion::SimpleAudioEngine::sharedEngine()->playEffect("bird1.mp3");
```

}

How can I implement something similar in Spritekit/swift where I can have `X` amount of soundfiles (or bird cheeping) in a random order with a small gap (or wait) in-between? Can this be done with `SKActions`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `SKAction` I implemented it like this:

load sounds:

```
let cheep1 = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("bird1.mp3", waitForCompletion: false)
//and so on
```

Create a wait time and forever call sequence:

```
func beginRandomCheeping(){
    let sequence = (SKAction.sequence([
        SKAction.waitForDuration(2.0),
        SKAction.runBlock(self.playRandomSound)
    ]))

    let repeatThis = SKAction.repeatActionForever(sequence)
    runAction(repeatThis)
}
```

Randomise sound and play:

```
func playRandomSound() {
    let number = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(9)))

    switch (number){
    case 1:
        runAction(cheep1)
        break
    case 2:
        runAction(cheep2)
        break
       .
       .
       .
    case 9:
        runAction(cheep9)
        break
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

And just call `self. beginRandomCheeping()` somewhere in the game logic.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is put the sound files into an array, set up an audio player and then create a function that plays the sounds randomly. Then use a timer that calls the function at whatever time interval you want. So:

```
Class GameScene {
    var soundFiles = ["bird_sound1", "bird_sound2"]
    var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

func setupAudioPlayer(file: NSString, type: NSString){
    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(file as String, ofType: type as String)
    let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path!)
        do {
            try  audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url)
        } 
            catch {
            print("Player not available")
        }
    }

func playRandomSound() { 
    let range: UInt32 = UInt32(soundFiles.count)
    let number = Int(arc4random_uniform(range))

    self.setupAudioPlayer(soundFiles[number], type: "wav")

    self.audioPlayer.play()
}

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    _ = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(7, target: self, selector: #selector(GameScene.playRandomSound), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

}
```